# Is there a way to stop Safari from grabbing focus on error when you're coding

Tags: typescript, next.js, browser, safari

Everytime an error pops up while I'm typing code in a Next.js app, safari insists on grabbing focus to tell me the error. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

I need the app open so I can see changes as I code. However I don't want it to keep grabbing focus anytime an error happens. I've had a look in the settings and can't seem to find as setting that seems to fix it.

I just want to type code and open browser when I want it.